# WPf animation with WinMM

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I would like some informations about animation in WPF

because i need really accurate rendering, i've decide to use a Multimedia timer instead of the default animation timer...

So I would like to know how does the animation clock work... i was thinking of raising tick event every 2ms and call a dispatcher invoke (i'm not sure that 2ms interval is enought for moving a line but if my understanding is good, dispactcher will manage that, no ?!?

```
public void setTime(int TimeInMs)
        {
         AnimatedLine.Dispatcher.Invoke(
         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
         new Action(
           delegate()
           {
               AnimatedLine.X1 = TimeInMs / 10 * ZoomRatio;
               AnimatedLine.X2 = TimeInMs / 10 * ZoomRatio;
           }
       ));
```

is it the best way of doing that ?

Moreover, i would like to know how you can test some collection every 2ms ...

For now, i really think that it's impossible to loop a collection every 2ms (for example of 100 objects) so i've decide to use a dictionnary ... (using the Key as time reference ..) if there is better option i'll be glad to hear ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. If the main thread can't cope with modifing+rerendering your visuals, `Actions` will stack up in the `Dispatcher` until something really bad happens.

Instead, take a look at [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx). Basically, This event is raised once per frame, so you can animate your objects in it before rendering.

Of course, there is no notion of *frame rate* here, and you can't predict at which interval this event is raised. So consider basing your animation on the time elapsed since last frame.

It's good animation practice anyway.

Comment: I don't really understand... Dispatcher isn't made for managing that kind of problem ?.  the most important things for the animation is that it 's syncronise perfectly with the MultiMedia Timer, like a clock, i've try to use dispatchertimer, but it can't handle a clock precision, by the way he lost almost 1 second every 10, depending of cpu charge ///

Comment: If you impose a frame rate to a rendering system (in your case 1 frame every 2ms, or 500fps) you gonna have problems if it can't cope with it. If you enqueue 500 actions per second in the dispatcher, and it can only process 100 actions per second, the queue will keep growing and your animation will look odd. So, do not impose a frame rate, instead, animate your objects based on the time elapsed since last animation.

Comment: Ok thanks, it 's totally make sense, and works ! but should i need to remove the CompositionTarget.Rendering event if the TimeValue doesn't change ( because i get this value for each frame )